# Should the determinant of a $0\times 0$ matrix be defined as $0$ or $1$?

Tags: definition, determinant

Let $A$ be the $0\times 0$ matrix and let $\det(A)$ be its determinant. I am wondering if $\det(A)$ should be defined as $0$ or $1$.

- If we use the definition that determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix $(a_{ij})$ be defined as $\displaystyle\sum(-1)^{\tau(j_1\cdots j_n)}a_{1j_1}\cdots a_{n{j_n}}$, where $\tau(j_1\cdots j_n)$ is the inversion number of the permutation $j_1\cdots j_n$, then since there is no term present, $\det(A)$ should be defined as $0$.
- If we expand the $1\times 1$ matrix $(1)$ along the first row, we obtain

$$1=\det(1)=1\cdot\det(A),$$ which implies that $\det(A)$ should be defined as $1$.

Which definition of the determinant of the $0\times 0$ matrix $A$, if any, makes more sense here?

Comment: Honest nonsnarky question:  why does it matter?

Comment: The definition of a determinant would give an empty sum, which conventionally is $0$.

Comment: Some arguments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762537/what-is-the-determinant-of/1762542 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913141/is-the-0x0-matrix-zero-times-zero-matrix-a-well-defined-concept

Comment: This is  very similar to the question as to whether $0^0$ should be zero or one.

Comment: Suppose you solve a system of $0$ linear equations for one of the $0$ unknowns using Cramer's rule. The result is either $\frac11$ or  $\frac00$ depending which definition you choose. Which makes most sense—the nonexistent unknown is $1$, or the nonexistent unknown is undefined? I think the second. But there might be other contexts where $1$ is the appropriate choice.

Comment: Empty sums and empty products are used to simplify induction-proofs. But what is the use of an empty matrix ?

Comment: @Peter Because when we solve this problem for a $0\times0$ matrix, we can move to $-1\times-1$ matrix :)

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Nope, it would give a $1$-element sum, since the $0$-th symmetric group $S_0$ has $1$ element.

Comment: But this element is empty b/c the matrix has no entry.  Plus the sum is defined with indices greater than or equal to 1 making it empty when the max index is 0.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: The element is an empty product, and thus equals $1$ by definition. The sum is a sum over permutations, not over elements of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$.

Comment: darij is of course correct. Just to add some detail, the trivial function $f \colon \varnothing \to \varnothing$ is the unique element of $S_0$. (Defining functions as relations, this is the empty relation from the empty set to itself.) It has no inversions. So, in every way, the determinant of the empty matrix is 1.